# How to search by choices with inmagik/django-search-views

Tags: django

For example, school grade 3. School table stores min and max grades. Elementary has K-5, Middle has 6-8, and High has 9-12. I have stored the grades as K, 1st, 2nd, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Used Djangos widgets ChoiceField